# C# JavascriptSerializer failing with EF object: RecursionLimit exceeded

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, serialization

I wanted a cheap way to clone a database object.  My plan was to serialize and then deserialize the object.  My code is as follows:

```
var newHireRequisition =_context.NewHireRequisitions.Single(x => x.newHireRequisitionPk == newHireRequisitionId);
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        js.RecursionLimit = 1;
       var json = js.Serialize(newHireRequisition);
        NewHireRequisition newReq = js.Deserialize<NewHireRequisition>(json);
```

As you can see, I set recursion level to one to keep from traversing the relationships of the NewHireRequisitions table.  I believe that this is a **bug** in the *'Serialize'* function.

When this code runs, I get an exception on the Serialize command.  The exception is:

> System.ArgumentException: 'RecursionLimit exceeded.'

The datamodel looks like this:
[image]
   but I only want the one object in the middle (NewHireRequisition), not the related rows.

Any help with this technique would be appreciated, or another way to shallow clone an entity framwork data object.

Comment: Documentation states that [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) should be used instead of [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx). Not sure if that will help, but something to check.

Comment: what documentation are you referring to @crashmstr ?

Comment: @StealthRabbi at the top of the JavascriptSerializer document I linked.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Curious that MS recommends using a third party lib :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @crashmaster!  Looking at the [newtonsoft web page](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm), I see that the Json.Net serializer supports LINQ to JSON, while the .net native JavaScriptSerializer does not.  That resolved my issue.

Comment: What was your resolution exactly?

Comment: I converted the object to a string using the SerializeObject method and then I created a new object using the DeserializeMethod, casting the object to my object type.  See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm for more information.